# How to synthesize a Rocket system?

Tags: riscv

I am trying to familiarize myself with the RISC-V ISA and Rocket Chip. I have set the `CONFIG=DefaultSmallConfig` and generated Verilog code using `make verilog` command in `vsim` directory. I have a few questions about the outputs and how to synthesize the system using Design Compiler (DC).

1. How can I remove the ports and wires that are related to debugging? I only need to synthesize the core and its peripherals, not the debugging related modules/wires.
2. Is the top-level module `ExampleRocketSystem`? I have to set `current_design` in DC and need to know what the top-level module is.
3. Other than the `freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultSmallConfig.v` output file, what do I need in order to run a full DC synthesis?
4. Assuming that I use the output Verilog file and no other files for DC synthesis, I get a lot of unresolved references and registers that are removed due to being constant. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Its difficult to remove the debugging ports in general and I'm not sure how to do it cleanly. Its also worth noting that if you don't include a peripheral to boot off you will want to keep the debug port to help you load test programs.

2) Yes `ExampleRocketSystem` is the top level module

3) You will need an implementation of the memories used in your design as well. By default you should have a `*.behav_srams.v` file in generated-src that have a simple verilog behavior model of rams you can include that should turn into a bunch of flip-flops in DC. If you have access to SRAMs you would likely replace these flip-flops with those.

4) You should not get unresolved references but it is reasonable to get registers being removed due to being constant.